# Is it more difficult to publish in a journal when not affiliated with an institution?

Tags: independent-researcher, publishability, reputation, independent-study

Can one generally expect it to be more difficult to publish in a journal when one is not affiliated with an institution? I like the idea of being an independent researcher at some point in the future, but I'm wondering whether getting my pieces published might get a little more difficult? Do people have experiences with this?

Comment: Regarding the issue of whether this might be a duplicate: Note that I am not asking whether one has to be affiliated with a university to publish papers, but whether this is more difficult when one isn't.